# SQL Server - Foreign key creation to multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a requirement where I need to create a foreign key for more than 200 tables. Ex, there is emp table which has ID has primary key, now the 200 tables have emp_id, which I need to reference to emp.id.

I know I can write 200 alter statements to create the foreign key. Is there an easier way to create with one simple script?

Please advise. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you need 200 tables? Sounds like you database might benefit from a review of its normalization?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick to do it

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @sql += ' 
    ALTER TABLE ' + Object_name(object_id)
               + '
            ADD CONSTRAINT FK_'
               + Object_name(object_id)
               + '_EMP_emp_id FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES EMP(id);'
FROM   sys.COLUMNS
WHERE  NAME = 'emp_id' 
--Print @sql
EXEC Sp_executesql
  @sql
```

**Note :**

1. Print `@SQL` variable and check the generated `SQL` is good
2. Above code consider's all the 200 table has the same name `'emp_id'` to which foreign key is created
3. This may fail when the `'emp_id'` column has bad data (ie) a `'emp_id'` which is not present in `EMP` table

Answer (score 0):

You could probably generate the `alter table` statements dynamically using `information_schema.columns`. Something like this should get you started:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '+ TABLE_NAME +
 ' ADD CONSTRAINT FK_'+ TABLE_NAME +'_Emp FOREIGN KEY ('+ COLUMN_NAME +')'+
 ' REFERENCES emp (Id)'+
 ' ON DELETE CASCADE'+
 ' ON UPDATE CASCADE;'+
 ' GO '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'emp_id'
```

Comment: In `emp` table column name is `ID` not `emp_id` so I don't think we need that `table_name` condition